# Continuity of a function in a special topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

i have this exercise :

Let $\tau$ be a familliy from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ consisting by $\mathbb{R}$ and any set such that it's complement containes $[x_0]$ where $[.]$ s the floor function,  where $x_0>10$

How to studythe continuity of this function with two methods:

$f:(\mathbb{R},\tau)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},|.|)$ defined by $$x\mapsto f(x)=\begin{cases} 0,x\notin \mathbb{N}\\ 1; x\in\mathbb{N}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I don't understand the definition. Could you write it as a formula? Is it the included point topology perhaps? Is $x_0$ fixed or variable?

Comment: $x_0$ is a point bigger then 10

Comment: A fixed point? not dependent on the open set?

Comment: we say that a set is open, if it's complement contains $[x_0]$

Comment: SO you mean there is a fixed $x_0 > 10$ such that $\mathcal{T}  = \{ A \subseteq \mathbb{R} : x_0 \notin A \lor A = \mathbb{R} \}$. This is called the excluded point topology.

Comment: yes it is this topology @HennoBrandsma

Comment: What is the inverse of any open set?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma i don't know , how to see what is the inverse of any open set

Comment: not always $x_0$ can be not in $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, $\mathcal{T} = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}: p \notin A \lor A = \mathbb{R}\}$, the excluded point topology w.r.t. some $p = \lfloor x_0 \rfloor  \in \mathbb{N}$.

Well, if $O_0 \ni 0$ and $O_1 \ni 1$ are disjoint in $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology then $f^{-1}[O_0] = \mathbb{N}$ and $f^{-1}[O_1] = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$. Only $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is open (the one not containing $p$). So $f$ is not continuous.

[comments asked for another method] Ok, for $f$ continuous and any subset of $A$ of the domain, we have $f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}$, and this charcterises continuity. So to disprove continuity, we can find a counterexample to this: What are closures in this topology? The closed sets are exactly $\emptyset$ and all sets that do contain $p$. (these are the complements of the open sets). 
We know that  $p \in \mathbb{N}$ so we take  $A = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{N}$. Note as $p \notin A$, $\overline{A} = A \cup \{p\}$ (clearly the smallest closed set containing $A$), and $f[\overline{A}] = \{0,1\}$ ($p$ maps to $1$ the rest to $0$) while $f[A] = \{0\} = \overline{f[A]}$, contradicting the closure formula for this specific $A$.

Also, note that all non-empty closed sets intersect (in $x_0$), so as $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are both closed, if $f$ *were* continuous their inverse images would be non-empty disjoint closed sets, contradiction.

I'll stop floging the dead horse now. :)

Comment: What about a seconde method please

Comment: @Vrouvrou Why would you need a second method? What do you count as methods? inverse image of closed sets also works, e.g. Local continuity ? nets? Or closure formulas like $f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}$? You already know hat $f$ is never continuous. What do other methods add to that?

Comment: it is in the exercise like this , but we don't know nets .

Comment: can you explain me how we prove contuity using $f(\overline{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$  please

Comment: @Vrouvrou see my edits. $f$ is now truly dead (not continuous )